# How to push a different set of changes to master?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have two branches in local. Staging and master.

There are some changes already pushed to staging. However, I don't want to push these changes to master.

If I have a second set of changes I need to push immediately to master. How can I do this without merging my first set of changes from staging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git `cherry-pick` option to pull in master exact commit.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick SHA1_of_commit
```

You can take SHA1_of_commit with `log` command

```
$ git log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
* 9121391 2012-09-16 | Studio sweeper fix in offices controller. (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, heroku/master, master) [Nick Kugaevsky]
* a7720f9 2012-09-16 | RBP improvements [Nick Kugaevsky]
* 5d0db9f 2012-09-16 | RBP improvements [Nick Kugaevsky]
* a35cd96 2012-09-16 | Home controller clean up [Nick Kugaevsky]
  ^^^^^^^ – SHA1_of_commit
```

Comment: It is uniq id of every commit. I've updated my answer with this info.